# jQuery click on a inside of ul and get it's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to register click on the element a in ul list and get id of the a.

```
$("#nativeLang > ul > li > a").click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This code is not working.
I found another way:

```
$("#nativeLang > ul").on("click", "a", function(event){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

But here I cannot get id of the clicked element a.

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown" id="nativeLang">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="l-6">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Add your html markup as well to your question please.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5nty3rau/

Comment: Added HTML fragment.

Comment: @Tolyas, your code is working fine, what are you seeing? Both methods are working: http://jsfiddle.net/5gghwnba/2/

Comment: The only problem that I can think of is that the DOM might be loaded dynamically after the JS is sourced.... however, you said yourself that the second method using delegation for the anchor is working... so there should be no reason why it wouldn't see the ID.

Comment: @smerny Ok it's working in this fragment. But I'm getting "undefined" message in whole site. http://kazy.kitaper.net/ The DOM is same but script is outdated.

Comment: @Tolyas, those anchor tags don't even have IDs... the list item tags have IDs... but they are all empty. `<li id=""><a href="javascript:nativeLangChoice(3)">English language</a></li>`

Comment: @smerny It's old. Just for demonstrate structure. But problem already solved. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dynamically inserting these `<li>` tags, then you need to use `$(document).on(...);`

```js
$(document).on("click", "#nativeLang > ul > li > a", function( event ){
   $('#Result').html( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="dropdown" id="nativeLang">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="l-6">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<div id="Result" ></div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I can help :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
   <li class="dropdown" id="nativeLang">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#" id="l-6">English</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
```

JS:

```
$("#nativeLang > ul").on('click', 'a', function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/avamdM/)

Comment: I know, this is just an example because I CAN'T see his dom.

Comment: @smerny there, no onclicks in the DOM xP. happy?